# For Gamma distribution, use MLE or MoM?

Tags: python, maximum-likelihood, gamma-distribution, scipy, method-of-moments

For Gamma distribution, is it better to use MLE(maximum likelihood estimation) than MoM(method of moments) to estimate the shape and scale parameters?

Also, in python SciPy, does gamma.fit use MLE? I'm trying to run a few python simulations to compare MLE and MoM on estimating the shape and scale parameters of Gamma distribution.

Comment: The docs say `gamma.fit` can use both methods: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.

Comment: "Better" at what? / better by what metric? E.g. if you mean "better = lower MSE" you may get a different answer from "better = easier implementation" or "better = faster to run".

Answer (score 15):

**Use MLE.**

Gamma distributions start approximating Normal distributions for large shape parameters (where both MoM and MLE ought to be equally fine), and the scale parameter merely establishes a unit of measurement; so the focus of the comparison ought to be on small shape parameters and varying the sample size.

Because MLE is justified only asymptotically, usually the smallest sample sizes give it the most trouble.

So, here are histograms of the estimates for 4000 simulated datasets of size $10$ with a shape parameter of $0.5$:

[image]

The true values are marked by red lines.  Clearly MLE is superior to MoM here, with less bias and much less spread in estimating the shape and a little less spread and less bias in estimating the scale.

These patterns persist across all sample sizes.  They continue through medium values of the shape parameter.  Once the shape exceeds $5$ or so, it becomes difficult to distinguish these estimators using histograms.

(The MoM implementation shown here is based on the first and second moments, which is standard.  The shape is estimated as $\bar x^2/v$ where $\bar x$ is the sample mean and $v$ is the variance (mean squared difference from the mean) and the scale is estimated as $v / \bar x.$)